# Didn't understand relationship 'AccountContactRelation' in FROM part of query call

Tags: apex, soql, accountcontactrelation

I'm getting the following error message:

> System.QueryException: Didn't understand relationship 'AccountContactRelation' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

`Select Email, Id, (Select ContactId, AccountId From AccountContactRelation) From Contact`

In AccountContactRelation object there are two lookup fields for Account and for Contact.

Please advise how to avoid such error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the *child relationship name*. You can always find it by using a script like the following:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Contact.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == AccountContactRelation.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

Paste the relationship name verbatim into your subquery, rather than the child object name.

Notice that you have two `FROM` clauses:

```
Select Email, Id, (Select ContactId, AccountId From AccountContactRelation) From Contact
```

In your subquery, you need to use the relationship name. In your top level query, you need to use the API Name of that SObject. Change `AccountContactRelation` to `AccountContactRelations` and you query should compile.

Comment: Strangely, I am getting null in debug

Comment: +1 nice way to get the exact ChildRelationshipName

Comment: +1 It is actually on child `AccountContactRelation` on which we are getting relationship field and not  child `Contact`. Modified it, hope you dont mind

Comment: Ah, yeah. Whoops.

Comment: @salesforce-sas after executing the script the `system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());` is giving me as a result `AccountContactRelations`.

Comment: Yeah notice how that differs from what you have in your subquery `FROM` clause.

Comment: Pasted the relationship name verbatim but get another error message: `System.QueryException: sObject type 'AccountContactRelations' is not supported.`

Comment: @sdfcadmdev Make sure you enabled Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts feature. And the API version of the class is set to the latest version.

Comment: @Vijay Ganji Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts feature is enabled and the class is set to the latest version. Still get the same error message `System.QueryException: sObject type 'AccountContactRelations' is not supported.`
Please advise what else I can try to avoid such error message.

Comment: It sounds like you replaced the incorrect `FROM` clause. Without seeing what you changed the query to, it is impossible to help you further.